# Raster to point - not in the centre of the cell

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, point

The raster to point does the following:

The raster will be converted to a point feature class using the ArcGIS Raster to Point tool. This tool creates a point at the center of each raster cell, except noData cells.

My questions is if there is a way to convert a raster to point but not creating a point at the centre of the raster rather than in one corner? This is to do an experiment of how different distributions across the cell would influence my analysis.

ArcMAP 10.2